# How to Remove all Android -Tools (ADB and fastboot) plus SDK from Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit)

Tags: android, linux, shell, ubuntu

I installed Android SDK in order to root my android phone, using script obtained thus:

```
wget http://linuxundich.de/static/android_sdk_installer.sh

chmod +x android_sdk_installer.sh

sudo ./android_sdk_installer.sh
```

(on my system: `sudo /home/xxx/android_sdk_installer.sh`)

Next, I also installed "android-tools" package (adb and fastboot) in 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 from WebUd8 ( http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-adb-and-fastboot-android-tools.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Then I used:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fsutil
```

to backport the Ubuntu Raring builds to Ubuntu 12.04

Just discovered the packages (android-tools, adb and sdk) take too much valuable space and would like to remove them, together with all associated packages.

Need comprehensive guide.

Thanks.

PS.
I can provide the text of shell script android_sdk_installer.sh, though it may also be obtained from link above.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
sudo apt-get purge android-tools-adb
```

Uninstall android-tools-adb and it's dependencies

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove android-tools-adb
```

Comment: sudo apt-get purge eclipse* 
returns:
0 updated, 0 new installed, 0 to be removed und 2 not updated.

rm -r ~/.eclipse/
returns:

rm: »/home/xxx/.eclipse/“ could not be removed: File or folder not found

Comment: you can add 'purge' to remove also local files